# POST does not return but hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I am running a JUnit test and the following code is stuck in line "server.post("/..." and does not return control (red square button in Eclipse). Here is the code and the log. Am a beginner, please help.

```
import org.junit.Test;
/**
 * @author jooby generator
 */
public class createTemplateNodeTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateTemplateNode() 
              throws UnsupportedOperationException, Exception { 
        System.out.println("started ");
        String json = "{\"prefLabel\":\"New Template 1\",\"altLabel\":\"NT\",\"cpus\":\"2\",\"memory\":\"1024\",\"requires\":[\"http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/7a7dbfb4-e6be-42ed-b78e-8cc6c9853e1b/6.8\",\"http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/12114f34-1bce-4417-9aea-d94da009efe4/5.5\"]}";
        server.post("/api/createTemplateNode").body(json, "application/json").expect(200)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        System.out.println("ended");    
    }
}
```

The BaseTest class is:

```
import org.jooby.test.AppRule;
import org.jooby.test.Client;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import com.dts_inc.z2c.z2c_ws.App;
/**
 * @author jooby generator
 */
public class BaseTest {
  /**
   * One app/server for all the test of this class. If you want to     start/stop a new server per test,
   * remove the static modifier and replace the {@link ClassRule} annotation     with {@link Rule}.
   */
//  @ClassRule
  @Rule
//  public static AppRule app = new AppRule(new App());
  public AppRule app = new AppRule(new App());
  /**
   * One client per test. It creates a new HTTP client per each of the test method you have.
   */
  @Rule
  public Client server = new Client("http://localhost:9090");
}
```

The resulting log (in Eclipse) is:

```
started 
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,832]-[netty task-3-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.z2c_ws.App - Incoming request: 
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,832]-[netty task-3-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.z2c_ws.App - temp2...<http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1> sys:requires <http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/7a7dbfb4-e6be-42ed-b78e-8cc6c9853e1b/6.8>.

[2016-08-24 14:20:18,832]-[netty task-3-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.z2c_ws.App - temp2...<http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1> sys:requires <http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/12114f34-1bce-4417-9aea-d94da009efe4/5.5>.

[2016-08-24 14:20:18,832]-[netty task-3-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.z2c_ws.App - # Template Node Configuration
@prefix : <http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/>. 
@prefix cpe: <http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0/>. 
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>. 
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>. 
@prefix sys: <http://www.dts-inc.com/systemspec#>. 
@prefix ver: <http://www.dts-inc.com/versioned#>. 
@prefix tag: <http://www.dts-inc.com/asset#>. 
@prefix org: <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#>. 
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>. 
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>. 
@prefix geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>. 

:f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1 a sys:TemplateNode;
    ver:hasHead <http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1/2016-08-24T18:20Z>.

<http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1/2016-08-24T18:20Z>
    a sys:TemplateNode;
    skos:prefLabel "New Template 1";
    skos:altLabel "NT";
    ver:firtVersion "true"^^xsd:boolean;
    ver:timeStampVersion "2016-08-24T18:20Z"^^xsd:dateTime;
    ver:isVersionOf :f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1;
    tag:cpus "2";
    tag:memory "1024".
<http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1> sys:requires <http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/7a7dbfb4-e6be-42ed-b78e-8cc6c9853e1b/6.8>.
<http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/f12847dd-db2a-4539-8ce1-19b9e8bd9df1> sys:requires <http://z2c.dts-inc.com/id/12114f34-1bce-4417-9aea-d94da009efe4/5.5>.

[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClient - executeQuery++
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - SparqlClientHandler Ctor
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientInitializer - Intializer Ctor
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientInitializer - Instance: com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientInitializer@18f177a
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientInitializer - Handler: com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler@4c53aa
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClient - Uri: http://cmoe3lblazegraph01.cmoa3s.com:8080/blazegraph/namespace/nairv/sparql
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,864]-[RxComputationScheduler-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClient - Connecting.
[2016-08-24 14:20:18,879]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientInitializer - Pipeline Handler: com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler@4c53aa
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - STATUS: 200 OK
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - VERSION: HTTP/1.1
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - HEADER: Server = Apache-Coyote/1.1
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - HEADER: Content-Type = application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - HEADER: Content-Length = 61
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - HEADER: Date = Wed, 24 Aug                 2016 18:20:12 GMT
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - HEADER: Connection = close
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - CONTENT {
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - Chunks initialized.
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - <?xml version="1.0"?><data modified="12" milliseconds="120"/>
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - } END OF CONTENT
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - Subscriber in handler: rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber@1e8e0ae
[2016-08-24 14:20:19,035]-[nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] DEBUG com.dts_inc.z2c.module.sparql.SparqlClientHandler - Chunks: UnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 61, cap: 61)
```

Comment: Unrelated hint on code quality: even in a unit test, do not hardcode such kind of json strings. Write a little helper utility that builds the string for you; based on simple input, like a map that you prefill with keys/values. Having to write (and read) such ugly strings distracts one from the actual intent of the test case. Besides that: great first question!